# How to make Woocommerce brand page header image to be displayed in the real size without adjusting and covering full page container?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, header

My Woocommerce brand page header banner (Thumbnail) is not displayed in the original size, it is somewhat zoomed in. When I asked about that my theme support he wrote:

"That section has cover background image, so as per the nature it auto resize the image size to adjust and cover full container and also it is parallax, so it is better to have some more height in your image like 1920px X 1000px."

My image size was 1920x600.
When I added more height it does not fix this problem, because it again is somewhat zoomed in and loses quality, and also some part of image.

So - **How can I make my Woocommerce brand page header image to be displayed in the real size, without this zooming effect? Without adjusting and covering full container?** I should mention that this zooming effect is also seen in my main page header slider.

My image size would be 1920x600 and I wish that it is displayed in the original image size.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem I added a CSS code:

```
.parallax-fix.page-title-shop {
background-size: 100% !important;
}
```